# How to get the value of last mysql fetch data? PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do this:

Check the top 10 values of points.

Here is my condition:

- If there are less than 10 records (rows) found, e.g give bonus
- If the points is in top ten (among hundreds records/rows), give bonus.

So, what i do is (wrong method):

```
SELECT points FROM `scores` WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 9 , 1
```

That will only work if i have more then 9 (at least 10) data/records.

Is there any other way?

I am thinking of using this(not very good though):

```
 SELECT points FROM `scores` WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Then get the last value of mysql_fetch_assoc data. Thus, how do I get the last value of mysql_fetch_assoc data?

Comment: give a sample input & output sceanrio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous query is close to what you want:

```
SELECT points FROM (
  SELECT points, score 
  FROM scores 
  WHERE id = '1' 
  ORDER BY score DESC 
  LIMIT 10
) AS top_ten 
ORDER BY score ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

If you want to stick with mysql_fetch_assoc getting the last value you can utilize mysql_data_seek.

Something like this:

```
<?php
// ... $result is the result set from your query

$result_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($result_count > 0)
{
    mysql_data_seek($result, $result_count - 1);
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
SELECT points FROM (SELECT points FROM scores WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY score LIMIT 1
```